# VBA error 91 - data extraction from multiple workbooks/workssheets

Tags: vba, excel

So, in my final attempt to complete my code, i am working with this

```
Sub MACRO2BATAR()

Dim lngFirstRow As Long, lngLastRow As Long, cRow As Long, lngNextDestRow As Long, i As Integer
Dim shSrc As Worksheet, shDest As Worksheet
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim WbName(1 To 5) As String
Dim intAppCalc As Integer 'added variable to store original calculation setting

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
intAppCalc = Application.Calculation 'store original calculation setting
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

WbName(1) = "CARREFOUR"
WbName(2) = "EDF"
WbName(3) = "SOCGEN"
WbName(4) = "TOTAL"
WbName(5) = "SANOFI"



For i = 1 To 5

lngNextDestRow = 2
'changed the workbook references
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = WbName(i)
Set shDest = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet  '''Feuille de destination (sheetDestination)

Workbooks.Open ("Users:uknowwho:Desktop:ProjetVBA:" & WbName(i) & ".xlsx")

For Each shSrc In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'changed ThisWorkbook to ActiveWorkbook

        With shSrc
            'added condition to check if there is data in column "B"
            If Not .Columns(2).Find(What:="*", LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False) Is Nothing Then
                lngFirstRow = 2
                lngLastRow = .Columns(2).Find(What:="*", LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

                For cRow = lngFirstRow To lngLastRow
                        If .Cells(cRow, 2) <> .Cells(cRow - 1, 2) Then
                            .Range("B" & cRow).Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("A" & lngNextDestRow)
                            .Range("D" & cRow).Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("B" & lngNextDestRow)
                            .Range("D" & cRow + 1).Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("C" & lngNextDestRow)
                            .Range("E" & cRow).Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("D" & lngNextDestRow)
                            .Range("E" & cRow + 1).Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("E" & lngNextDestRow)
                            .Range("F" & cRow).Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("F" & lngNextDestRow)
                            .Range("F" & cRow + 1).Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("G" & lngNextDestRow)
                            lngNextDestRow = lngNextDestRow + 1
                        End If
                Next cRow
            End If
        End With

 Next shSrc

 Workbooks(WbName(i) & ".xlsx").Close
 Next i

Application.Calculation = intAppCalc 'restore original calculation setting
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

But im getting a runtime error 91, and the `IngLastRow = .Columns(2)`... line highlighted. I don't understand as it worked previously when i was working in one workbook only.

EDIT: I updated the last version of code i got running. Thanks to @Branislav Kollár The problem is not the error anymore, but the fact that the data are only extracted when i=1. After that the other sheets are created in the workbook, but the data are not extracted anymore and the four new sheet are left blank. It may have to do with this, but im not sure  :

```
Set shDest = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet  '''Feuille de destination (sheetDestination)
```

I'am running out of idea to make this work :(

LAST EDIT: so all i needed to do was to move  lngNextDestRow = 2 just after the beginning of the For each i = 1 to 5 loop. It was working all along but the datas were being pushed down due to the fact that lngNextDestRow increases +391 per workbook on average. 
Thanks you so much  Branislav ;)

Comment: Please, check the sheet where the error occurs. Is the column "B" on this sheet blank? The error could rise, because you are trying to get the `.row` of `nothing`.

Comment: And another question. You want to run the code on each sheet of each newly opened workbook, right?

Comment: Hi, Column B is a column full of dates, over 1 year usually. Every sheet in every workbook i want to extract data from has the same format. 
I want the code to be hosted in a completely new workbook, and be able to extract all the data i need in one attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Changes:

1. Presuming you want to copy values from every sheet in each newly opened workbook : `For Each shSrc In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'changed ThisWorkbook to ActiveWorkbook`
2. Added `Application` setting lines (for speeding up)
3. Added condition to check if column "B" is blank `If Not .Columns(2).Find(...) Is Nothing Then`

---

### Code:

```
Sub MACRO1BATAR()

Dim lngFirstRow As Long, lngLastRow As Long, cRow As Long, lngNextDestRow As Long, i As Integer
Dim shSrc As Worksheet, shDest As Worksheet
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim WbName(1 To 5) As String
Dim intAppCalc As Integer 'added variable to store original calculation setting

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
intAppCalc = Application.Calculation 'store original calculation setting
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

WbName(1) = "CARREFOUR"
WbName(2) = "EDF"
WbName(3) = "SOCGEN"
WbName(4) = "TOTAL"
WbName(5) = "SANOFI"

For i = 1 To 5

lngNextDestRow = 2 'this line needs to be inside the main loop (argh!)

'changed the workbook references
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = WbName(i)
Set shDest = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet  '''Feuille de destination (sheetDestination)

Workbooks.Open ("Users:uknowwho:Desktop:ProjetVBA:" & WbName(i) & ".xlsx")

    For Each shSrc In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'changed ThisWorkbook to ActiveWorkbook

            With shSrc
                'added condition to check if there is data in column "B"
                If Not .Columns(2).Find(What:="*", LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False) Is Nothing Then
                    lngFirstRow = 2
                    lngLastRow = .Columns(2).Find(What:="*", LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

                    For cRow = lngFirstRow To lngLastRow
                            If .Cells(cRow, 2) <> .Cells(cRow - 1, 2) Then
                                .Range("B" & cRow).Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("A" & lngNextDestRow)
                                .Range("D" & cRow).Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("B" & lngNextDestRow)
                                .Range("D" & cRow + 1).Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("C" & lngNextDestRow)
                                .Range("E" & cRow).Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("D" & lngNextDestRow)
                                .Range("E" & cRow + 1).Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("E" & lngNextDestRow)
                                .Range("F" & cRow).Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("F" & lngNextDestRow)
                                .Range("F" & cRow + 1).Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("G" & lngNextDestRow)
                                lngNextDestRow = lngNextDestRow + 1
                            End If
                    Next cRow
                End If
            End With

     Next shSrc

     Workbooks(WbName(i) & ".xlsx").Close
Next i

Application.Calculation = intAppCalc 'restore original calculation setting
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

---

Notes:

1. Your code is quite well written I think. There is nothing redundant or unnecessary. If this is one of your first macros then *Well done, sir!*
   The only thing I was thinking about is merging the copied cells using `Union` but I don't think that can be applied, since you are rearanging them as you paste.
2. Here is some more info about the error you were getting [Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264506%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

### Edit

Changed 3 lines just below the `For i = 1 To 5`, changed `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook` (this is **not** the same situation as before, in point 1). I'm presuming you have some master workbook, with this macro in it, and to this master workbook you want to copy the data to.

---

Just to be sure, in the line `Workbooks.Open ("Users:uknowwho:Desktop:ProjetVBA:" & WbName(i) & ".xlsx")` shoudn't you use `\` as a folder delimiter?

---

### Edit 2

We'll get rid of the *Active* books and sheets and try more specific approach.

1. Try adding a new variable `Dim newWB As Workbook`
2. Change the line, where you set the Destination sheet to `Set shDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WbName(i))`
3. Change the line, where you open the workbooks to `Set newWB = Workbooks.Open("Users:uknowwho:Desktop:ProjetVBA:" & WbName(i) & ".xlsx")`
4. Change the line for sheet looping to `For Each shSrc In newWB.Worksheets`
5. Change the line for closing the new workbook to `newWB.Close`

---

If the files open correctly and the new sheets come out blank, then there is no data in the columns "B" in the source sheets. I see no other possibility. Check the sourse sheets.

Comment: Thank you for your notes sir! I'm trying to update the code at this very moment.

Comment: It worked almost perfectly. The program takes about 4 min to run. 
It created every new sheet according to the name of WbName (i) and went to open the workbooks, but it only extracted the datas from the first Workbook, being CARREFOUR.XLSX ...

Comment: As far as I knwo, when we **open a new workbook**, it should be on the top => therefore **ActiveWorkbook**. Only if the new workbook is not yet opened, it will loop the old one. Maybe try `For Each shSrc In Workbooks(WbName(i) & ".xlsx").Worksheets`. If my guess is right, this should produce an error. If so, we'll use `DoEvents` method. So try the `For Each shSrc In Workbooks(WbName(i) & ".xlsx").Worksheets` please.

Comment: I change what you suggested, and It did exactly the same. It worked for CARREFOUR only, even if all the sheets were created in the current workbook, their not filled with any data. 
I did not encountered any error ... :s

Comment: Very stubborn code. >:| Did some changes to my answer, see **Code** and **Edit** section for comments. If this does not work, I may be out of ideas.

Comment: I'm going to try with the last changes, I am also running out of idea, i might try to find the last row for my loop inside each worksheet differently, also i don't really know if there is a better way. 
Yes the code is supposed to be in a completely new workbook just created for the occasion. I tried with the "/" and it wasn't working, i found that the ":" did, i think its an osx particularity

Comment: I wish i could upvote you man by the way! thanks for your help. I am trying the last changes ;)

Comment: I edited the main post. It did not work either :(
I am really wondering why the datas are extracted for i=1 and not after...

Comment: You're welcome for the help, hope we'll break through. We're missing something obvious, need a new pair of eyes.

Comment: Added yet another **Edit 2**.

Comment: OOOOH man! I just figured this out! 
It is because of the lngNextDestRow = 2... 
I have to reset it after the loop in one workbook is over! 
It was working super fine since the beginning i believe, i just didn't see the result... Each Workbook leads to around 390 line of data in each new worksheet of the new wb. So on the fifth sheet the datas started line 1564...
You're the man! Thank you so much, i can finally beggining the real work, the trading strategy program :)

Comment: I feel really really dumb i didn't check the weight of the newwb or somthing just to have realized the datas were in fact there, just not in the right place. 
i just can't thank you enough!

Comment: Just as I thought *"We're missing something obvious"* :D I'm really glad I could help and even more that it's working now, and that **YOU** figured it out. I learned a lot about debugging other's code. Nice cooperation this project. Hope you'll make a few bucks out of it :). I will amend my answer to the last version.

Comment: Haha ye, it was kind of obvious now that i think about it :) And i am proud of myself, but really thankful to you. Working on code is really really interesting, it is very logic and all, it like a game really. I already feel i learned a lot.
I probably won't make money from that, its a school project ;) I'll probably be back on my way to make the next part. thanks!